# Ubuntu 16.04 CLI SIP Client

Tags: 16.04, command-line, sip, linphone, twinkle

I need a CLI SIP client that will be controlled via Python script.
I have tested **a lot** of clients, like Linphone (which crashes for me on my Ubuntu 16.04 x64) or Twinkle (Which simply doesn't work).

Does anyone knows a simple CLI SIP Client that can save me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this package can be controlled via a Python script, but "Blink" by Ag-Projects does at least *use* Python. Blink {checked to work with both 16.04 and 18.04} handles multiple SIP accounts, also those requiring a lot of configuration, and can be configured more than Linphone. To install it requires some typing. Links and docs at their site http://ag-projects.com/

Comment: I just found out about the command line tools for the same package, but see that an answer has already been added to link to it so all is fine. {To https://sipsimpleclient.org/testing/ }